# Deleting a row based on values of the next row on multiple columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to delete rows from my dataframe when the next one meets certain conditions. Let's say that my dataset is:

```
raw_data = {'SessionID': ['S1', 'S1', 'S1', 'S2', 'S2', 'S2', 'S2', 'S2', 'S3', 'S3', 'S3', 'S3', 'S3', 'S3'], 
    'Event Action': ['Action', 'Action', 'Filter', 'Action', 'Action', 'Action', 'Filter', 'Filter', 'Action', 'Filter','Action', 'Filter', 'Filter', 'Action'], 
    'Timestamp': ['T1.1', 'T1.2', 'T1.3', 'T1.1', 'T1.2', 'T1.3', 'T1.3', 'T1.4', 'T1.4', 'T1.5', 'T1.7', 'T1.7', 'T1.8', 'T1.9']}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['SessionID', 'Event Action', 'Timestamp'])

df

 SessionID  Event Action    Timestamp
0   S1         Action          T1.1
1   S1         Action          T1.2
2   S1         Filter          T1.3
3   S2         Action          T1.1
4   S2         Action          T1.2
5   S2         Action          T1.3
6   S2         Filter          T1.3
7   S2         Filter          T1.4
8   S3         Action          T1.4
9   S3         Filter          T1.5
10  S3         Action          T1.7
11  S3         Filter          T1.7
12  S3         Filter          T1.8
13  S3         Action          T1.9
```

Given any *row* and being *row1* the next one, I want to delete *row* when:

```
if df[row:'SessionID'] == df[row1:'SessionID'] 
and df[row:'Event Action'] == 'Action' 
and df[row1:'Event Action'] == 'Filter' 
and df[row:'Timestamp'] == df[row1:'Timestamp']
```

For instance, in the dataset above the rows that should be eliminated are 5 and 10. I'm not that expert with fuctions in python, but I've tried:

```
def cleanfilter(row):
    row1 = row + 1
    if df[row:'SessionID'] == df[row1:'SessionID'] and df[row:'Event Action'] == 'Search Action'and df[row1:'Event Action'] == 'Search Filter' and df[row:'Timestamp'] == df[row1:'Timestamp']:
    df.drop(df.index[row])

df.apply(cleanfilter,axis=1)
```

But i'm constantly receving: "TypeError: ('must be str, not int', 'occurred at index 0')". I don't know what to google anymore... Any advice would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean `row1:'SessionID'`, I don't see a row 1

Comment: My apologies for the bad formulation.
*row1* is the row immediately after *row*. So, taken any specific *row*, *row1* is the one immediately after *row*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create masks for your conditions and then apply them to your `df` with a negation since we are looking to delete the rows that meet the conditions.

```
m1 = (df['SessionID'] == df['SessionID'].shift(-1))
m2 = (df['Event Action']=='Action')
m3 = (df['Event Action'].shift(-1)=='Filter')
m4 = (df['Timestamp']==df['Timestamp'].shift(-1))
df[~(m1 & m2 & m3 & m4)]
```

Output:

```
         SessionID Event Action Timestamp
0         S1       Action      T1.1
1         S1       Action      T1.2
2         S1       Filter      T1.3
3         S2       Action      T1.1
4         S2       Action      T1.2
6         S2       Filter      T1.3
7         S2       Filter      T1.4
8         S3       Action      T1.4
9         S3       Filter      T1.5
11        S3       Filter      T1.7
12        S3       Filter      T1.8
13        S3       Action      T1.9
```

Comment: That perfectly works and is way more elegant than what I was trying to do. I've read now the .shift pandas documentation, cool. However I'm not fully understanding the last sentence: df[~(m1 & m2 & m3 & m4)]. 

Does it mean: print the dataframe excluding those conditions?

Comment: @E.Faslo, it returns the copy of the `df` that do not satisfy `(m1 & m2 & m3 & m4)` (all the conditions.) Rather than deleting the rows that satisfy the conditions, we are looking for the rows that do not satisfy conditions. I hope it clears your doubts.